# PineScript with more than two supertrend

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am trying to write a pine script (Version 4) where there will be three supertrend indicators to create a buy or sell signal.

- line must be drawn based on buySignal or sellSignal criteria.
- signal will be generated if two out of three supertrends are giving an entry signal

Following is the code. What am I missing. Chart is not showing any buy or sell signal.

```
B_Cond1 = trend_1 == 1 and trend_1[1] == -1 and trend_2 == 1 and trend_2[1] == -1
B_Cond2 = trend_1 == 1 and trend_1[1] == -1 and trend_3 == 1 and trend_3[1] == -1
B_Cond3 = trend_2 == 1 and trend_2[1] == -1 and trend_3 == 1 and trend_3[1] == -1

buySignal = B_Cond1 or B_Cond2 or B_Cond3

S_Cond1 = trend_1 == -1 and trend_1[1] //== 1 and trend_2 == -1 and trend_2[1] == 1
S_Cond2 = trend_1 == -1 and trend_1[1] == 1 and trend_3 == -1 and trend_3[1] == 1
S_Cond3 = trend_2 == -1 and trend_2[1] == 1 and trend_3 == -1 and trend_3[1] == 1

sellSignal = S_Cond1 or S_Cond2 or S_Cond3

plotshape(buySignal, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor = color.white, transp = 0)
plotshape(sellSignal, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor = color.white, transp = 0)
```

Comment: your should try adding what is your output any errors

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug your conditions with plots. Simplify your `buySignal` by separating it:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

plot (B_Cond1 ? 1 : 0, title = "B_Cond1", color = color.red)
plot (B_Cond2 ? 1 : 0, title = "B_Cond2", color = color.green)
plot (B_Cond3 ? 1 : 0, title = "B_Cond3", color = color.orange)

plot (buySignal ? 1 : 0, title = "buySignal", color = color.blue)

plot(close)
```

and check whether your conditions meet each other or not.

Same for `sellSignal`.